# Shower tub leaking - is this the washer I replace?

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet

I have a slow drip out of the tub faucet even when the cold water is off. I have disassembled the cold water handle and attached is a picture of the stem. I think that the washer in the middle is the culprit. Can anyone verify if this is the likely cause? Recommendations for proper way to fix?

[image]

Comment: The washer between the screw and the valve stem is what closes fresh water from flowing.  The black o-ring on the stem keeps the stem from leaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *"Can anyone verify if this is the likely cause?"*

I can't verify but I can tell you that you are on the right track. The flattish washer in the middle is called a [bibb washer](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0781/6377/products/191308_usn_57fa4e69-6382-4f60-ace3-e69519dc2a63_large.jpeg?v=1438721123) and (as @Tyson's comment relates) pushes up against a hole in the faucet through which water flows.

The "hole" is not just a simple hole, it is actually a (normally) removable [faucet seat](https://www.thetoolstore.ca/catalog/Faucet_Seats.jpg) which is also replaceable/repairable, but likely requires a special tool to remove.

The rubber bibb washers get a rough groove worn into them, break apart, or become soft over time, compromising their ability to hold back the water flowing through the hole in the seat.

The pic below is probably nothing like your faucet, but it does illustrate how a "bibb" style valve functions (in the pic they call the bibb washer a stem washer- lame):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I replaced the bibb washer, but it is still dripping. You did give what I think the correct answer is though. I suppose the faucet seat is the next most likely culprit.

Comment: Yes, the seat can often be removed with a hexagonal or square "seat removal tool", then replaced. Alternatively, they can often be "dressed" in place; that is, the worn seat surface is made smooth by grinding it with a special tool.

Comment: Thank you Jimmy. Once I knew what to look for, I was able to replace the seat. No more dripping!